# Android AVD starting error

Tags: android, eclipse, performance, android-studio, android-emulator

I am getting this error when i start an avd in android studio.
Any help would be appreciated. And also unable to start android studio except from terminal.

PANIC: `HOME` is defined but could not find `Nexus_4_API_21.ini` file in `$HOME/.android/avd`
(Note: avd is searched in the order of `$ANDROID_AVD_HOME,$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/avd and $HOME/.android/avd`)

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I had especially installed Android Studio on my D: drive (for space reasons). On my installation, the `avd` directory was located in `D:\MyInstall\.android\.avd`

The solution for me was to [define a Windows environment variable (user variable)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bEroNNzqlF4) with Variable name: `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` and Variable value: `D:\MyInstall`

I restarted Android Studio and the emulator worked.

This appears to be a bug in the Android Studio installer, since I explicitly stated the D: location in the install wizard. The installer should probably have set this variable.

Comment: Adding a software for just resolving this issue ? I do not think that's a correct advice. That's like going to GUI for any missing command.

Comment: @saurshaz I only advise setting a variable. I didn't have to install anything.

Comment: @saurshaz I don't understand your comment. If you down-voted, please see the edit - I added the word "had" to clarify (hopefully) that it was how my Android Studio was initially installed (I'm not advising people to install anything). The fact that it wasn't installed on C: is likely the reason that the environment doesn't find AVD. My answer is similar to Exception's except that the variable is not set to the same value.

Comment: I'm sorry!! The phrasing gave me the impression that it was an advice to install Android Studio. I was wrong. Read the answer again (more carefully) Peace !!!

Comment: This is exactly that ! @GabsSukumar Please mark this post as solve !

Answer (score 1):

Set the variable ANDROID_SDK_HOME to < home directory > / .android / .avd

For creating this variable under Win7, please go to control panel -> system -> advanced parameters -> environment variables. In the "user variables" block, Click on "new". Please fill the variable name and its value. Close all dialog by clickin on button "OK" and launch android studio.

Go through this [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81937) for more solutions if the above one doesn't work out for you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I set the ANDROID_AVD_HOME environment variable to "C:\Users\DELL.android\avd".

If the error still persists try running android studio as administrator in windows, it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I also came across to the same problem while launching Android emulator launch.

PANIC: HOME is defined but could not find `testAvd.ini` file in `$HOME\.android\avd`

```
(Note: avd is searched in the order of $ANDROID_AVD_HOME,$ANDROID_SDK_HOME\.android\avd and $HOME\.android\avd)
```

There are two solutions I found for the above problem.
Goto `run` and type `regedit` for windows and check the path set in the registry variables in under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->Android Studio
```

And check the `.android\avd` referring to the location of your `testAvd.ini` location. If not, either correct it or put your `ini` file at the `UserSettingsPath` present in your disc location.

Answer (score -2):

This solved the problem for me. Just follow the link. It explains why it happens and how to get around it. :)
http://kalpa-gunarathna.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-emulator-not-starting-on-ubuntu.html

Comment: Please provide a description of the solution rather than providing just a link. If that blog ever goes down, this post will no longer be useful.