# My Android Studio Emulator isn't responding or running

Tags: android, ubuntu, emulation

If I run my virtual andorid emulator, I get this message. I'm new to android studio. Any help would be appreciated.

ps,I use Ubuntu as my OS.

/root/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_23_x86 -netspeed full -netdelay none

PANIC: HOME is defined but could not find Nexus_5_API_23_x86.ini file in $HOME/.android/avd
(Note: avd is searched in the order of $ANDROID_AVD_HOME,$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/avd and $HOME/.android/avd)

Comment: You can have a look on this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983364/android-avd-starting-error