# Not able to run the first Hello World on Android Studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I tried to follow the first example on android.com in order to run the first hello world project. I tried both Nexus 5 and Nexus 6 in AVD manager, but I get the following error:

```
D:\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5_API_23_x86 -netspeed full -netdelay none 
PANIC: HOME is defined but could not find Nexus_5_API_23_x86.ini file in $HOME\.android\avd 
(Note: avd is searched in the order of $ANDROID_AVD_HOME,$ANDROID_SDK_HOME\.android\avd and $HOME\.android\avd)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Restart android studio

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983364/android-avd-starting-error) question provides an answer.

Comment: Does your HOME directory contain non-ascii chars or spaces?

Comment: yes that worked. thanks user1982116

Answer (score -1):

Just install Eclipse. It is open source software.